# How can I use ADB shell to mount sdcard

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I have Xperia S and I have already installed cwm recovery.
I need to use recovery to backup,restore or flash roms from my sdcard.
But every time I have the problem:"E:can'not mount /sdcard".
I have tried to mount it using adb using :

adb shell
su
mount -o mnt/sdcard

I still have the problem.
Can someone help me to use adb correctly to solve the problem or have any better idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see if [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1296694) on XDA fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you but this thread supposed I have external card I can format it

Comment: How can I deal with my internal storage because my phone has not micro card